# Bad request during POST request to influxDB from asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, post, influxdb

I'm trying to send a POST request to my local influxDB.
I'm getting StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request'"

```
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
 HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://localhost:8086/write?db=mydb");
 requestMessage.Content = new StringContent("cpu_load_short, host = server01, region = us - 345345 value = 0.34564 345345");
 HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(requestMessage).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

In my Postman I put "http://localhost:8086/write?db=mydb" and "cpu_load_short,host=server01,region=us-345345 value=0.34564 345345" in my body(raw) and it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try setting the content type to something like

```
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

or if you know and are sure about the encoding type as well then use this

```
requestMessage.Content = new StringContent("cpu_load_short, host = server01, region = us - 345345 value = 0.34564 345345", Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); // or whatever is the encoding type
```

The `ContentType` property contains the media type of the request